# War not deploying in tomcat after obfuscation with proguard 6.02

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat, proguard, obfuscation

I have obfuscated the classes using Proguardgui.jar and included the obfuscated classes in a war file but I am getting the following logs. My war is not deployed. I am using Spring 4.17, Mysql 5.7.21, Apache Tomcat 9.0.6. Thanks in advance.

> [2018-04-27 12:29:40,305] [] []
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO 
>   o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization completed in 41973 ms 27-Apr-2018 12:29:40.328 SEVERE
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
>   Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate
>   container log file 27-Apr-2018 12:29:40.328 SEVERE
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context
>   [/] startup failed due to previous errors 2018-04-27 12:29:40
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO 
>   o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root
>   WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Apr 27 12:28:59 IST 2018];
>   root of context hierarchy [2018-04-27 12:29:40,354] [] []
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO 
>   o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root
>   WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Apr 27 12:28:59 IST 2018];
>   root of context hierarchy 2018-04-27 12:29:41
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO 
>   o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' [2018-04-27
>   12:29:41,291] [] []
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO 
>   o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 27-Apr-2018
>   12:29:41.423 WARNING
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc
>   The web application [] registered the JDBC driver
>   [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web
>   application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has
>   been forcibly unregistered. 27-Apr-2018 12:29:41.424 WARNING
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [] appears to have started a thread named
>   [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This
>   is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
>   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source) 
>   com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
>   27-Apr-2018 12:29:41.461 INFO
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive
>   [D:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.6\webapps\.war] has finished
>   in [157,901] ms

Comment: Sounds like maybe `One or more Filters failed to start.` Perhaps `Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file`?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I am new to obfuscation where should I look for the log file  how do I enable these filters

Comment: Start by reading every file in Tomcat's `logs/` directory.